# Compare two objects with specified keys in TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I am trying to compare two objects but only with three keys instead of all keys. It looks like this:

```js
Object.keys(StateA)
   .filter((k) => [k == 'name', 'x', 'y'])
   .every((k) => StateA[k] == StateB[k])
)
```

I am getting false results; what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to filter keys if you already have/know the ones to compare beforehand; use `every` just as you are:

```js
const A = { a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, x: 3, y: 4, z: 5 };
const B = { a: 0, b: 2, c: 3, x: 3, y: 4, z: 6 };

const match = ['a', 'x', 'y'].every(key => A[key] === B[key]);
console.log(match);
```

Keep in mind a simple check like this *may* give you false positives - it depends on what you want. One case would be a key missing in one object but present in the other set to `undefined`. If that's the case, you may want to also check for the presence of the key:

```js
const A = { a: 0, b: 1, c: undefined };
const B = { a: 0, b: 1 };
const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const match = keys.every(key => A[key] === B[key]);

console.log(match); // true

const stricterMatch = keys.every(key => (
  key in A && key in B && A[key] === B[key]
));

console.log(stricterMatch); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
export function hasSameProps (source: Record<string,unknown>, target: Record<string,unknown>) {
    Object.keys(source).every(key => target.hasOwnProperty(key));
```

or

```
for (const key in ObjA) {
   const current = ObjB[key];

   if (!current) {
       // does not exists
   }
}
```